# Prove that the genus $\gamma(G) \leq cr(G)$ for every graph $G$

Tags: graph-theory

a) Prove that $\gamma(G) \leq cr(G)$ for every graph $G$

b) Prove that for every $k \geq 1$, there exist  a graph $G$ such that $\gamma(G)=1$ and $cr(G)=k$

Let $G$ be any graph . If $G$ is planar then $\gamma(G)=cr(G)=0$. So assume that $G$ is non-planar, that mean $cr(G)\geq1$

If $G$ is embedded on a torus $\gamma(G)=1 \leq cr(G)$.

If $G$ is not embedded on a torus ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need any formula's here: just add a handle for each crossing.

For part b, consider $C_3\square C_k$ ($\square$ indicating the Cartesian graph product)

Comment: if I add a handle then the number of handle must be equal the number of crossing, right? But from your answer, it seems like one handle can hold more than 1 crossing. Is this the same reason for part b) that $\gamma(G)=1$?

Comment: Certainly a handle can often hold more than one crossing, that's why you are asked to prove an inequality, not an equality. For part b you need to see that the graph is not planar (we handled that in one of your other questions), but that you can easily draw it on a torus without crossings.

Comment: I know that every connected graph can be embedded on a torus, but what about disconnected graph. Is there any graph that can't be embedded on the torus?

Comment: I tried to put part a) together into a proof, I wonder if you can please  check if it make sense

Comment: No, that makes no sense, better remove it. Just imagine that you have a drawing of a graph with $k$ crossings. Now at each crossing 'lift' one line above the other by using a crossing. Try to avoid thinking in formulas here, use intuitive reasoning. There are many graphs that cannot be embedded on a torus WITHOUT CROSSINGS.

Comment: I think I understand the part that add a handle at every crossing, but I'm still unsure about the part that one handle can hold more than one crossing, can you give me one example of that?

For part b), it's easy to see that the crossing number of that graph is $k$, but the $\gamma=1$ suggest it's embedded on a torus, and I have a hard time to see it. Can you explain it a little bit more please? My professor is Chinese and I don't understand her accent at all.

Comment: On the WIKI page for torus http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus you can see a picture of how something like a $C_{20}\square C_{20}$ (the numbers are probably wrong, but they are quite high) is embedded without crossings on a torus. That should help :)